# What the setVisibleActivities method does?

Tags: android, google-plus

The typical initialization of a PlusClient instance for accessing Google Plus from an Android app is something like this:

```
PlusClient mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
            "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .build();
```

I do not understand at all this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.Builder.html#setVisibleActivities(java.lang.String...)

I do not know what are these "activity types", and why they are there, and how are they used by the PlusClient, so I do not know which of them I should use in my app...

Answer (score 2):

[App Activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities) are ways for your application to save and share your user's actions to their Google+ account. As per the documentation you linked, there are a number of specific [types of activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types/) that correspond with different types of actions your users could take in your application.

Comment: So they have nothing to see with Android Activity java class, have they?

Comment: @Fran - correct. Google+ App activities are a totally separate thing from Android activities.