# setVisibleActivities undefined

Tags: android, google-play-services

Ever since upgrading to Android SDK API 19 (KitKat), I'm getting the following error when trying to build my project:

`The method setVisibleActivities(String, String) is undefined for the type PlusClient.Builder`

If I look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16800732/276949), it has a link to the API where apparently this function was documented - but it appears to have simply disappeared from there as well.

Here is the code in question:

            `PlusClient mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .build();`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by replacing

```
PlusClient mPlusClient =
    new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setVisibleActivities(
        "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
        .build();
```

with

```
PlusClient mPlusClient =
    new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setActions(
        "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
        .setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN") // Space separated list of scopes
        .build();
```

Errors should be gone now.

You can find more about that here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_plusclient

Comment: what this line is actually doing?? can u plz elaborate??

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with a project I was trying to build. Apparently it needed the [Google Play Services for Froyo](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) library instead of the normal one. It wasn't clear because they're both referred to as `google-play-services_lib` in the project.properties file.